# Objective C - Objects not being added to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom class which has a property, which is of type NSMutableArray. When I try to add an object, it does not give me an error, but does not add that object either. Following is that class.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (atomic,strong) NSMutableArray *prop1;

@end
```

This is another class, of whose object I'm trying to assign to Class

Then, in another class, I am trying to add an object to that property.

```
NSString *test = @"";
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
classA.prop1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[classA.prop1 addObject:test];
```

But, when I am debugging, `classA.prop1` has `0 elements`.
It worked earlier, without an issue. But this behaviour started off suddenly. I cannot remember changing anything in the project. This behaviour is seen across the entire project. I am at a loss. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: It's not obvious where is your breakpoint / check of `NSMutableArray` elements count.

Comment: @Kamil.S I'm checking in the line after the `[classA.prop1 addObject:test];` line. I haven't added all the code here.

Comment: is there a particular reason that you have declared your property as atomic?

Comment: @dreamBegin Not really.

Comment: I just tried exact same thing and it had 1 element as it should

Comment: Add a breakpoint after adding the `test` object then in the debugger type `po classA.prop1.count`

Comment: Why is test @""; that is an empty object; you are trying to add an empty object to an empty array, it's not un-reasonable that the count is 0. If you used `addObject:nil` would you expect the count to go up? This may or may not be the reason, I'm not familiar enough to know off the top of my head, but I'd suggest making your test string actually contain data and seeing if that fixes it. Let us know and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your **NSMutableArray** array as nonatomic

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *prop1;

@end
```